# Multiple db queries with RABL and Mongoid/Moped

Tags: mongoid, rabl, moped

I have a simple app that uses rabl and mongoid 3.1.0, with this action:

```
# index
@products = current_shop.products
```

The rabl code looks like this:

```
# index.json.rabl
collection @products
extends 'api/products/show'

# show.json.rabl
object @product
attributes :id
```

When I hit it, the logs show 4 requests related to @products:

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=bamboo_development collection=products selector={"$query"=>{"shop_id"=>"511c7866fd896b1908000002"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.5682ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=bamboo_development collection=products selector={"$query"=>{"shop_id"=>"511c7866fd896b1908000002"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=-1 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (1.1139ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=bamboo_development collection=products selector={"$query"=>{"shop_id"=>"511c7866fd896b1908000002"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.4492ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=bamboo_development collection=products selector={"$query"=>{"shop_id"=>"511c7866fd896b1908000002"}, "$orderby"=>{:_id=>1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.4332ms)
```

When I do this:

```
@products = current_shop.products.search(params[:query])
render text: @products.map(&:name).join(",")
```

I get only one request related to @products:

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=bamboo_development collection=products selector={"shop_id"=>"511c7866fd896b1908000002"} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=0 skip=0 batch_size=nil fields=nil (0.4611ms)
```

The duplicated queries look strange, does anyone know why that happens? It doesn't call child objects, just somewhat different collection queries, from what I see.

Comment: Try @products = current_shop.products.to_a

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people getting same problem. Most likely because of rabl configuration problem. As recommended by Aymeric above, just do:
@products = current_shop.products.to_a